# What camera was used to create this hyper-saturated look?

Tags: portrait, reverse-engineering

I am looking to recreate this type of photography, but I cannot find an answer anywhere on the internet - hoping you'll be able to help.

Here is the reference photo: [image: Bella Hadid]

I absolutely love the beachy style of this photography, so any help would be truly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange - could you please read [Important information for asking "What's this effect?" questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions) and try and edit your question accordingly? "Beachy style" doesn't really mean very much other than maybe having some sand and waves in the background. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Erika, welcome to Photo.SE. I suspect the reason your question is being downvoted is because the simple answer is that the style is not camera-dependent. Also, as @PhilipKendall noted, questions about reproducing a specific style or effect are usually poorly asked or defined. It's okay that you "absolutely love the beachy style" of the photo. But other than the obvious being-taken-on-a-beach aspect of the photo (which is obvious), what, **in your opinion**, makes you love the photo, or aspects of it? If you can state that, we can help to edit your question to be better. Thanks. =)

Answer (score 1):

The look of that image can be achieved with pretty much any camera.  Use a normal focal length and fill flash.  Boost saturation.  Set temperature to around 7000K.

---

The model in that [Porter cover](https://models.com/Work/porter-magazine-porter-magazine-summer-2017-cover) is [Bella Hadid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bella_Hadid).  The photographer is [Terry Richardson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Richardson).  Richardson was [noted](https://off-camera-flash.com/english/2015/07/strobist-kit-5/) to use a Yashica T4 Super early in his career.  He later used the Panasonic GF1 and a Nikon DSLR with flash bracket to hold the flash next to the lens.

There is a series of articles, *How to Shoot like Terry Richardson* ([part 1](https://ilovehatephotography.wordpress.com/2014/07/02/how-to-shoot-like-terry-richardson-part-1-the-look/), [part 2](http://ilovehatephoto.com/2014/07/18/how-to-shoot-like-terry-richardson-part-2-the-setup/), [part 3](https://ilovehatephotography.wordpress.com/2014/08/22/how-to-shoot-like-terry-richardson-part-3-the-results/)).

[image: Terry Richardson with DSLR]

Answer (score 1):

As xiota's answer states, pretty much any camera can achieve the look of this photo with very little processing. A somewhat long focal length lens (in terms of portrait photography) helps to keep the model's head in apparent proportion to the shoulders and body. I'd say roughly 85–150 mm focal length (in terms of full frame 35 mm body).

The key to this type of photo is lighting: late afternoon or early evening sun creates warm golden tones (hence why the hour or so before sunset is called the "golden hour"), and the low angle of the sun creates plenty of opportunity for dramatic shadows, adding depth and contrast to the subject and the scene.